# Buildserv for Ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: build, ubuntu-14.04, build-server

I'm looking for some easy to configure BuildServ system that can fetch from a git repository every couple hours and then switches the git branch and then compiles it using scons.
It would run 2 builds Linux and Windows, if the compiling status is failed it would then change the image on the webpage to failed and link to the last build that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try jenkins server for Buildserv purpose. It has a community edition so you don't have to spend money as well. :)

below is the link.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu